# WDcloud EX2 - after factory restore can not be accessed ( Windows 10)

Tags: windows, networking, nas

I just factory restored a Western Digital NAS called WDcloudEx2 ( 2 bay hard-drive ).
I have 2 window 10 machine which worked flawless with it, and after restoring it, I can't map or access it.

On my Linux machine, mapping is as usual.

NAS has a static IP address as before (by the router, NAS is configured as DHCP).

On both windows machines, it can get accessed via its web address, but not on "Networks" as before. see [image: pic]

Comment: So you mean it does not show up as shown in the screenshot, or it does but you get some kind of error when you click on it?

Comment: @TomYan sorry for not being clear enough. Screen shot show current status while it shows under "Storage" (double click takes it to its dashboard webpage) and not under "Network"